# Create Vue.js component instance, on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm pretty new with Vue and I am trying to add another input box (which I have as a separate component), when clicking on a button.

```
<div>
    <Input id="school" label="school" class="school-input" />
</div>
```

When clicking on a button, I want to add another input field.

```
<Button btn-text="add new school" type="btn-edit" @click="add()" />
```

But I don't know what should I put in the add() method (since the input box is a component, and not just a regular html input), so that when I click on the button, I get a new empty input box below the existing one.

Thanks for your help and references.

Comment: please provide the vue or current component instance

Comment: Actually I don't have much code. I'm just having the input as a separate component where I have:

    <input
      :id="id"
      :type="type"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      :disabled="disabled"
      :value="value"
      @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
    />

And I was using this as a reference: 
https://codepen.io/izobiz/pen/vgeWaY

But I am really confused because here we are adding a new html element when clicking on the button, and I need to create an instance of the Input component...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a data property called `schools` which is initialized as an array and iterate over it using `v-for` then bound each school to an Input :

```js
Vue.component('Input', {
  props: ['value'],
  template: `<input  :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" />`
})

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {

    return {
      schools: [{
        name: ''
      }]
    }
  },

  methods: {
    add() {
      this.schools.push({
        name: ''
      })
    }
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="add">add new Schoold
</button>
  <Input v-for='(school,index) in schools' v-model="schools[index].name"></Input>

  <h3>schools:</h3>
  <pre>{{schools}}</pre>
</div>
```